# How do I use DisplayNameForModel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I tried using this as a header for a view but it returns an empty string. In the Razor layout, I have something like:

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCApp.Models.Model>
<h2>@Html.DisplayNameForModel()</h2>
```

Do I need to set something on the model definition itself? I tried a data annotation `[Display(Name="Model Name")]` but it is a build error:

*Attribute 'Display' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'method, property, indexer, field, param' declarations.*

The documentation [DisplayNameExtensions.DisplayNameForModel Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.displaynameextensions.displaynameformodel(v=vs.118).aspx) is terse. The syntax calls for a parameter, but says:

*No overload for method 'DisplayNameForModel' takes 1 arguments*

As the Usage section says "When you use instance method syntax to call this method, omit the first parameter"

So, how do I use this method to return something?

Comment: Not sure if it's just pseudo code, but you have a typo in <h2>@Html.Disp**al**yNameForModel()</h2>

Comment: @mike123 I fixed the typo and double-checked my code. That wasn't the issue (if only it were that easy).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just used the default MVC 5 template project in VS2013 and have the `@Html.DisplayNameForModel()` working with no issues.

First, you are using the wrong data annotation on your view model.  You want to use `[DisplayName("My Model Name")]` and not `[Display()]`

```
[DisplayName("Test View Model")]
public class TestViewModel

{
    public string TestProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Second, the html parameter you are seeing on MSDN is a required parameter for any Html helpers in MVC.  You do not have to pass anything for this value, the view engine does this for you.  So, in your view, you would use the following to get the Display Name that you set on the model as so.

```
<h2>@Html.DisplayNameForModel()</h2>
```

Now, your result should output the display name attribute you set in your html. *Note the **Test View Model** above the **Log In** text.

[image]

Comment: Not sure if it is relevant, but the models are ADO entities generated from a database. Would their declaration as a `partial` class make a difference?

Comment: @ShooShoSha - Shouldn't be an issue, however, you really should get in the habit of using view models in your views and not POCO classes from EF or wherever these data models came from.  View models allow much greater flexibility in what data you are sending to/from your view.  Anyways, ensure you are using the **correct** data annotation, which is `DisplayName` not `Display`

Comment: I have found the issue is the model itself is a `IEnumerable<T>`. I can annotate individual class models easily, just when I create a list of the model I lose the annotation from the context of  the HTML helper. Using a view-model achieves what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

try

> @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Name)

Comment: This question is about `DisplayNameForModel`.